# Difference between Redis GET/SET and hash tables

Tags: database, redis, hashmap

I'm new to Redis and databases in general. I'm confused about when I should use the GET/SET commands and when I should create a hash table and use the HGET/HSET commands.

Let's say I want to keep track of the prices of various products in a shop.

Using GET and SET:

```
SET pencil 3
SET eraser 4
SET calculator 60

GET pencil
GET eraser
GET calculator
```

Using HGET and HSET:

```
HSET mystore pencil 3
HSET mystore eraser 4
HSET mystore calculator 60

HGET mystore pencil
HGET mystore eraser
HGET mystore calculator
```

For this shop example, which method is preferred? What's the difference between using the GET/SET commands and using the HGET/HSET commands? What are some of their use cases?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Hashes](https://redis.io/docs/manual/data-types/#hashes) are used to store objects in Redis and `GET`/`SET` are used to store a single *string* (or *int*).

From your description, in your case there is nothing different with `HSET` and `GET`/`SET`. If your Redis database is used only for `mystore` object (or something similar), you can just use `GET`/`SET` with the *key*.

And if there are multiple similar `mystore` objects, I recommend to convert to *hash* since it will be much easier to organize the key-values.

For performance, key-value string and hash are both implemented using *dict* (hash will use [*ziplist*](https://redis.com/ebook/part-2-core-concepts/01chapter-9-reducing-memory-use/9-1-short-structures/9-1-1-the-ziplist-representation/) if data set is small). So it will always be O(1) time complexity.